# Error in setting actionbar in onResume

Tags: android

In onResume method of activity trying to set actionbar here is my code for setActionbar

```
protected void setActionBar() {

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customActionBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
    ivDrawerIconActionbar = (ImageView) customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.iv_drawer_icon);
    tvAppName = (TextView) customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.tv_app_name);
    ivAppLogo = (ImageView) customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.iv_app_logo);
    actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBar);
    ll_title = (LinearLayout)customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.ll_title);
    ivDrawerIconActionbar.setOnClickListener(this);

    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#B44041")); 
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
            ll_title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
            ll_title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}
```

and this is onresume method,here calling setactionbar()

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    setActionBar();

    super.onResume();
}
```

here adding stacktrace for crash. App crash is happening in setActionBar method pls tell me why crash is happening.sorry for english

Comment: move code of `onResume` to `OnCreate` method

Comment: Getting error at *actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

instead of

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Your custom view will be used if the display option I mentioned is set.

Answer (score 1):

Possible values for [`setNavigationMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setNavigationMode(int)) are :

- NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD
- NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST
- NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS

Remove this :  `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);`.

You can simply set Custom view in Actionbar with  [`actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(boolean))